# How to get index of a string in an a list

Tags: java, json, codeigniter, encoding

```
public int userCompare(String s1, int i1, String s2, int i2){
        String[] alphabety = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
        String[] firstThing = s1.split("(?!^)");
        String[] secondThing = s2.split("(?!^)");
}
```

How do I complete the following:

Create a method called userCompare that will return a -1, 1, or 0 based on the following: We have data for two users, A and B, each with a String name and an int id. The goal is to order the users such as for sorting. Return -1 if A comes before B, 1 if A comes after B, and 0 if they are the same. Order first by the string names, and then by the id numbers if the names are the same.

Comment: You should show an attempt to solve this yourself. If you get stuck, then explain where you are stuck. To improve your understanding of Stack Overflow and how to use it, may I suggest these resources:  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Ask / Answer Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: In the question body, the description of what is to be done, seems to be very different from what is being asked in the question header.  Also, in your sample code, the three `String []` seem to be not related to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd compare each component individually, and then use [`signum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-) to get strictly `1`, `-1` or `0`.

```
public int userCompare(User a, User b) {
    int retVal = a.getName().compareTo(b.getName);
    if (retVal != 0) {
        return (int) Math.signum(retVal);
    }

    retVal = Integer.compare(a.getId(), b.getId());
    return (int) Math.signum(retVal);
}
```

Side note - for the purpose of sorting in Java, you don't need to strictly return `1`, `-1` or `0`, you can just return an arbitrary positive, negative or zero value. In other words, the usage of `signum` is required by question, but isn't strictly required for sorting.

Comment: For reference, _[Comparable#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))_.

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize the *[String#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))*, and *[Integer#compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int))* methods here.

```java
int userCompare(String nameA, int idA, String nameB, int idB) {
    int t;
    if ((t = nameA.compareTo(nameB)) == 0)
        return Integer.compare(idA, idB);
    return t;
}
```

If you're looking to implement the actual comparison routine, review the *source* for each of those methods.
For a *String*, it's just a traversal of the *bytes*.

Here is utilized *StringLatin1#compareTo* method.
*[GitHub – OpenJDK – StringLatin1.java – compareTo(byte[], byte[], int, int)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21%2B9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringLatin1.java#L110)*.

```java
public static int compareTo(byte[] value, byte[] other, int len1, int len2) {
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    for (int k = 0; k < lim; k++) {
        if (value[k] != other[k]) {
            return getChar(value, k) - getChar(other, k);
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

And, for an *Integer* it's just a *relational*, and *equality*, operation.
*[GitHub – OpenJDK – Integer.java – compare(int, int)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L1432)*.

```java
/**
 * Compares two {@code int} values numerically.
 * The value returned is identical to what would be returned by:
 * <pre>
 *    Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param  x the first {@code int} to compare
 * @param  y the second {@code int} to compare
 * @return the value {@code 0} if {@code x == y};
 *         a value less than {@code 0} if {@code x < y}; and
 *         a value greater than {@code 0} if {@code x > y}
 * @since 1.7
 */
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```